pandas groupby expanding mean does not accept missing values
I've been looking to retrieve group-based expanding means from the following dataset:
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,2,2,2],'y':[1,2,3,1,2,3]})

and df.groupby('id').expanding().mean().values returns the correct:
array([[1. ],
       [1.5],
       [2. ],
       [1. ],
       [1.5],
       [2. ]])

However, in my specific case I have to deal with some missing values as well, so that:
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,2,2,2],'y':[1,pd.NA,3,1,2,3]})

My expected result applying the same logic would be to ignore the NaN in the computation of the mean, so that from df2.groupby('id').expanding().mean().values I would expect
array([[1. ],
       [1.],
       [2. ],
       [1. ],
       [1.5],
       [2. ]])

Instead, Pandas returns an error due to applying some type assertion to float in the backend. None of my naive attempts (e.g., .expanding().apply(lambda x: np.nansum(x)) are solving this. Any (possibly equally compact) solution?

You can convert column 'y' with pd.to_numeric, which will coerce pd.NaN into nan. The latter can be interpreted correctly by the following operations:
df2["y"] = pd.to_numeric(df2["y"])
df2 = df2.groupby("id").expanding().mean().values

[[1. ]
 [1. ]
 [2. ]
 [1. ]
 [1.5]
 [2. ]]


# Dataframe with missing values
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], 'y': [1, pd.NA, 3, 1, 2, 3]})

# Replace pd.NA with np.nan (required to ensure compatibility with float type)
df2['y'] = df2['y'].apply(lambda x: np.nan if pd.isna(x) else x)

# Convert column y to a float type
df2['y'] = df2['y'].astype(float)

# Group by id and compute the expanding mean (ignores NaN values)
expanding_means = df2.groupby('id')['y'].expanding().mean().values
print(expanding_means)


If y is all integers as in the example, one can just do df['y'] = df['y'].astype('Int64'). In general, you can do df['y'] = df['y'].fillna(np.nan).

fillna raises a FutureWarning
